# office 365 sso saml dot net web application integration

Tags: single-sign-on, office365, saml

**Hi**

Does office 365 provides SSO SAML?

**Requirement:** I have one **asp.net web application** from **my web application i need to login into my office 365 account( SSO )and again it should redirect back to my web application.**

Is it possible to do with office 365?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to integrate the Web App Sign In & Sign Out with Azure AD, we can using the use the OWIN authentication pipeline with code below:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
    new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        ClientId = clientId,
        Authority = authority,
        PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
    });
}
```

And we need to register the app with Azure AD to get the client Id. More detail you can refer to [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-devquickstarts-webapp-dotnet/).